# Create a function called priceLookup to find the price of a single item

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

First time posting on here. I am a bit stuck. The assignment is as follows:

Create a function called priceLookup to find the price of a single item. The function should accept the array of items and an item name (string) as parameters, and return the price of the item with that name. If the item cannot be found, return the string "No item found with that name"

** Assume this test data can be other arguments entered into the function ** ( I think I used the correct terminology)

//Test data for the problems

```
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]
```

Here is my code and where I am stuck:

```
function priceLookup(items, name){
 let result = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
   if (name == items[i].itemName){
   (result =+ items[i].price)
   } else { result = "No item found with that name"
      }
  }
  return result;
 }
```

So I guess my question is, why is my else statement cancelling out the if before it? If I remove that I pass the testing on getting the name called, but fail on if the name doesn't exist that it shows "No item found with that name"

Answer (score 0):

```
function priceLookup(items, name) {
  let result = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (name == items[i].itemName) {
      result += +items[i].price;
    }
  }
  if (result === 0) {
    return "No item found with that name";
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you find a match return it immediately. There is no need to look through the rest of the items.

As for the "No item found"...only return that after loop completes.

What is currently happening is as soon as an item that doesn't match is found you are changing result from a number to the message string and the loop keeps going through the other elements in array

```
function priceLookup(items, name) {

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (name === items[i].itemName) {
      // the return will break the loop and exit the function
      return items[i].price;
    }
  }
  // if loop completes no matches were found
  return "No item found with that name"
}
```

Other notes: Don't make `i` a global variable and use `===` for equality check

Comment: Thank you! As far as your notes, what do you mean by don’t make i a global variable? Sorry I literally started a full stack boot camp about 2 weeks ago with 0 coding knowledge,  so my terminology is certainly wanting at the moment. Understood on the === as that is more strict correct?

Comment: When you declare variables with `var, let or const` they are only available in the `scope` they are declared in. They can't be accessed outside that scope or collide with other variables with same name in higher level scope.  A global means it is accessible anywhere in the code base. So if your next function also used variable `i` they can collide. Do a quick search for a basic tutorial on scope. There are a lot of nuances to it but just getting the high level concept for now will help you going forward

Answer (score 0):

[Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is your friend. It's usually less buggy and more efficient to use a built in instead of rolling your own.

So your function would be:

```
function priceLookup(items, name) {
    let ret = items.find( x => x.itemName === name);
    return ret ? ret.price : "No such item";
}
```

Comment: Oh yea that looks much more simple. I guess since we haven’t gotten up to that yet I didn’t know too much about array.find. I can’t imagine if I learn things on the side like here it would be frowned upon. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: PS: In current browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari) you can use optional chaining and null coalescing operators to make this even more compact.


`return (items.find(x => x.itemName === name))?.price ?? "No such item";`

Answer (score 0):

```
function priceLookup(items, obj) {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].itemName == obj) {
            return items[i].price
        }
    }
    return undefined
}
```